# Chart JS Displays Only Bigger Dataset But Has Both Datasets?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

fairly new to JS and I have a strange issue with chart JS bar chart.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var bar = document.getElementById("chart-bar-11").getContext('2d');
    var data1 = {
        labels: ["Yesterday"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Win",
            data: [{{ gam }}],
            borderColor: '#4099ff',
            backgroundColor: '#4099ff',
            hoverborderColor:'#4099ff',
            hoverBackgroundColor: '#4099ff',
            
        }, {
            label: "Lose",
            data: [{{ results }}],
            borderColor: '#0e9e4a',
            backgroundColor: '#0e9e4a',
            hoverborderColor:'#0e9e4a',
            hoverBackgroundColor: '#0e9e4a',

        }]
    };
    var myBarChart = new Chart(bar, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data1,
        options: {
            barValueSpacing: 20
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

I have a simplke bar chart, but here is a screen shot of current behavior, super confused how this chart shows it has both datasets but will only display the larger dataset?

[image: Bar Chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up finding the options needed in another Chart JS post, this is what I was missing.

```
    var myBarChart = new Chart(bar, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data1,
        options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
    });
```

It appears he "beginAtZero" is what was missing. This now works as expected.